# Split mail to multiple recipients by postfix to single-recipient-mails before delivering to smarthost

Tags: postfix-mta

Is it possible to split all mails to multiple recipients into single mails with only one recipient before delivering to my smarthost?

I tried to get answer from https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html but i think there must be combined some of the configuration-options.